# React renders a child component only one time

Tags: reactjs, components, render

I'm trying to populate a TreeView component on demand. I'm getting the data in the componentDidMount function and then I insert those data into an array on the main component state. The componentDidUpdate is used to set the data array into the treeview root node. The fact is that the treeview doesn't renders the data unless it comes in static way, on demand it show simply nothing. Here is the code:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
    this.tree = {
      idx: 0,
      descript: 'Root',
      collapsible: true,
      collapsed: false
    };
  }

  receivingData = (data = []) => {
    this.setState({data: data});
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetchData(this.receivingData);
  }

componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.data.length !== this.state.data.length) {
      this.tree.children = [];
      for (let x of this.state.data) {
        this.tree.children.push({
          idx: x.idx,
          descript: x.name,
          collapsible: true,
          collapsed: false
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is the render method:

```
render () {
   console.log('getting here', this.tree);
    return (
      <div>
            <TreeView
              onNodeSelectionChange={this.onTreeNodeSelection} ref={this.treeViewContainerRefBuilder}
              data={this.tree} selectLeavesOnly={false} singleSelect/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The console log shows me the tree changes, but the TreeView renders only once. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're having here is that while `receivingData` will cause an re-render, you are editing `this.tree` in the `componentDidUpdate` method which occurs *after* the re-render has already happened, so your TreeView component will not re-render with the updated data.

Try using `componentWillUpdate` instead of `componentDidUpdate` so that `this.tree` is modified before the re-render occurs.

Comment: Thank you Mr. CD-jS, I did what you suggested and everything is just the same. I put the tree within the state and nothing occurs either.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
constructor (props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  data: []
};
this.tree = {
  idx: 0,
  descript: 'Root',
  collapsible: true,
  collapsed: false
};
}

receivingData = (data = []) => {
if (prevState.data.length !== data.length) {
    this.tree.children = [];
    for (let x of this.state.data) {
      this.tree.children.push({
        idx: x.idx,
        descript: x.name,
        collapsible: true,
        collapsed: false
      });
    }
  }
this.setState({data: data});
}

componentDidMount () {
 fetchData(this.receivingData);
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {

}
```

Note: Don't use componentWillUpdate as these methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code. Refer https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Hope this helps :)